# Grep across multiple files in Hadoop Filesystem

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop, grep

I am working with Hadoop and I need to find which of ~100 files in my Hadoop filesystem contain a certain string.

I can see the files I wish to search like this:

```
bash-3.00$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/mdhi-technology/b_dps/real-time
```

..which returns several entries like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 b_dps mdhi-technology 1073741824 2012-07-18 22:50 /apps/mdhi-technology/b_dps/HADOOP_consolidated_RT_v1x0_20120716_aa
-rw-r--r--   3 b_dps mdhi-technology 1073741824 2012-07-18 22:50 /apps/mdhi-technology/b_dps/HADOOP_consolidated_RT_v1x0_20120716_ab
```

How do I find which of these contains the string `bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc`?  Once I know, I can edit them manually.

Comment: Problem with this is, its not a UNIX file system, its a Hadoop File System, whenever I try to do like this `bash-3.00$ cd /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time
bash: cd: /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time: No such file or directory` I get no such file or directory. So I need some other way to tackle with this problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a hadoop "filesystem", not a POSIX one, so try this:

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time | awk '{print $8}' | \
while read f
do
  hadoop fs -cat $f | grep -q bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc && echo $f
done
```

This should work, but it is serial and so may be slow.  If your cluster can take the heat, we can parallelize:

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time | awk '{print $8}' | \
  xargs -n 1 -I ^ -P 10 bash -c \
  "hadoop fs -cat ^ | grep -q bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc && echo ^"
```

Notice the `-P 10` option to `xargs`: this is how many files we will download and search in parallel.  Start low and increase the number until you saturate disk I/O or network bandwidth, whatever is relevant in your configuration.

**EDIT**:  Given that you're on SunOS (which is slightly brain-dead) try this:

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hadoop fs -cat $f | grep bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc >/dev/null && echo $f; done
```

Comment: Problem with this is, its not a UNIX file system, its a Hadoop File System, whenever I try to do like this `bash-3.00$ cd /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time
bash: cd: /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time: No such file or directory` I get no such file or directory.

Comment: You're positive this directory exists?  Can you mount it to a  location, and then cd into it?

Comment: I am not sure whether I can do this or not as that folder has TB of data inside. And how I can mount it to a location by the way?

Comment: Thanks phs for the solution, so I can just copy paste the above command into bash prompt directly right? Or I need to do something else?

Comment: When I copy pasted the first command that you mentioned which is slow as said by you. In my screen this thing is getting printed continuously one line after another `grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
Usage: java FsShell [-cat <src>]
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
grep: illegal option -- q
` Any idea why? Or it is working fine?

Comment: Copy-paste should do it.  Mind, I don't have your cluster in front of me to test.  However based on http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html I feel this should work.

Comment: And after trying second command that you gave me, I am getting- `bash-3.00$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdmi-technology/b_apdpds/real-time | awk '{print $8}' | \  xargs -n 1 -I ^ -P 10 bash -c \  "hadoop fs -cat ^ | grep -q bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc && echo ^"
bash:  : command not found
` command not found, don't know why.

Comment: Good heavens.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14553/discussion-between-phs-and-rjchar)

Comment: Short answer: he's using SunOS, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with the approach

Comment: BTW, you can also pass -C to the ls command to avoid having to call awk: hadoop fs -ls -C /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to applying grep command on hdfs folder

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/coupons/input/201807160000/* | grep -c null
```

here cat recursively goes through all files in the folder and I have applied grep to find count.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hadoop fs -cat` (or the more generic `hadoop fs -text`) might be feasible if you just have two 1 GB files. For 100 files though I would use the [streaming-api](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) because it can be used for adhoc-queries without resorting to a full fledged mapreduce job. E.g. in your case create a script `get_filename_for_pattern.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q $1 && echo $mapreduce_map_input_file
cat >/dev/null # ignore the rest
```

Note that you have to read the whole input, in order to avoid getting `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` exceptions.

Then issue the commands

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar\
 -Dstream.non.zero.exit.is.failure=false\
 -files get_filename_for_pattern.sh\
 -numReduceTasks 1\
 -mapper "get_filename_for_pattern.sh bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc"\
 -reducer "uniq"\
 -input /apps/hdmi-technology/b_dps/real-time/*\
 -output /tmp/files_matching_bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/files_matching_bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc/*
```

In newer distributions `mapred streaming` instead of `hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar` should work. In the latter case you have to set your `$HADOOP_HOME` correctly in order to find the jar (or provide the full path directly).

For simpler queries you don't even need a script but just can provide the command to the `-mapper` parameter directly. But for anything slightly complex it's preferable to use a script, because getting the escaping right can be a chore.

If you don't need a reduce phase provide the symbolic `NONE` parameter to the respective `-reduce` option (or just use `-numReduceTasks 0`). But in your case it's useful to have a reduce phase in order to have the output consolidated into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

To find all files with any extension recursively inside hdfs location:

```
hadoop fs -find  hdfs_loc_path  -name ".log"
```

Comment: Yeah, I use this on daily purpose. And there are so many ways to use this command.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -find /apps/mdhi-technology/b_dps/real-time  -name "*bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc*"

hadoop fs -find /apps/mdhi-technology/b_dps/real-time  -name "bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc"
```

Comment: Just to add a clarification: This answer provides a solution for searching the string `bcd4bc3e1380a56108f486a4fffbc8dc` in the file path / file name, NOT in the contents of the file. Still useful though :).

For the latter, refer to [phs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697831/4528111) above.