# Search for a string or number range in a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I want to search in HDFS and list out the files that contains my search string exactly,
and my second requirement is that is there any possible way to search for a range of values in a file HDFS.

let suppose below is my file and it contains the following data

/user/hadoop/test.txt

101,abc
102,def
103,ghi
104,aaa
105,bbb

is there any possible way to search with the range [101-104] so that it returns the files which contains the following data range.

.

Comment: You've only listed one file here, but heard of MapReduce? That's about the only way to search your files

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your quick response.That is for an example i had listed one sample file here, but there are number of similar files in my HDFS, and you mean to say by MapReduce only way to fulfill my requirement . And secondly when i am using hdfs dfs -ls -R /  | grep [search_term] to search the files, it is listing out the entire list of files which contains a single character of search term but not the entire string of the search term.

Comment: You can't use `hdfs dfs` to recursively search all files. I literally mean MapReduce programming

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697810/grep-across-multiple-files-in-hadoop-filesystem

Comment: Your grep command there only searches filenames, not the file content for your number data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep across multiple files in Hadoop Filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697810/grep-across-multiple-files-in-hadoop-filesystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **display file names** having a pattern. Lets loop through hdfs directory which has files let say.

```
hdfs_files=`hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/|awk '{print $8}'`
for file in `echo $hdfs_files`;
 do
  patterns=`hdfs dfs -cat $file|egrep -o "10[1-4]"`
  patterns_count=`echo $patterns|tr ' ' "\n"|wc -l`
   if [ $patterns_count -eq 4 ]; then 
    echo $file;
   fi
 done
```

Now solution to second requirement "**search for a range of values in a file HDFS**" using shell command:-

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/hadoop/test.txt|egrep "10[1-4]"
```

output:-

```
101,abc
102,def
103,ghi
104,aaa
```

or just match first column

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/hadoop/test.txt|egrep -o "10[1-4]"
```

output:-

```
101
102
103
104
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but question wanted the file name that contains the range, so you can't `cat` any one file

Comment: Again, the question expects file names as output

Comment: @syadav Thanks for the inputs. I am expecting the file names as output

Comment: just save this shell into somefile.sh. run it via `sh somefile.sh 2>/dev/null`. You should get hdfs file names along with fully qualified path, those have all the mentioned matching patterns.