# Grep across multiple LZ4 compressed files in Hadoop Filesystem

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My question is very similar to [Grep across multiple files in Hadoop Filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697810/grep-across-multiple-files-in-hadoop-filesystem)

However, in my case, all the files are LZ4 compressed

```
$hadoop fs -ls /output

/output/a.lz4
/output/b.lz4
.......
```

A specific string `alice` appeared in `/ouput` 0 or more times. I want to see in which file `alice` appears